# Please explain how to use the AFX_EXTENSION_MODULE Structure

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

More specifically, why is the struct `AFX_EXTENSION_MODULE` used as

`"static AFX_EXTENSION_MODULE NVC_MFC_DLLDLL = { NULL, NULL };"`

when it is defined as

```
struct AFX_EXTENSION_MODULE{
    BOOL bInitialized;
    HMODULE hModule;
    HMODULE hResource;
    CRuntimeClass* pFirstSharedClass;
    COleObjectFactory* pFirstSharedFactory;
};
```

and what do the two `NULL`s in `{ NULL, NULL }` represent?

Comment: It surely was just blindly copy/pasted from an early MFC version.  It doesn't matter at all, remove the initializer to make you feel better.

Answer (score 0):

This extension module structure is included into a list of all extension modules (in the docs mostly mentioned as extension DLLs) loaded into an application. This list is used by the MFC to find class names to serialize and to find resources that are not located in the main module.

The structure is filled by AfxInitExtensionModule.

An extension module is included into the DLL chain by the creation of the CDynLinkLibrary object. This is usally done after AfxInitExtensionModule is called.

You find more Infos about extension modules/DLLs in the technical notes 33 and 58.